# explicit proof of pullback stability of epics in a topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

As in 
[Explicit construction of a initial object in a topos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493475/explicit-construction-of-a-initial-object-in-a-topos)
I'm looking an elementary proof of the fact that, in a topos, epimorphisms are stable under pullback or, equivalently, that images are stable under pullback.
Stardard proofs uses the fact that the pullback functor has right adjoint, hence it preserve colimit.

Proofs can assume the existence of initial object and the image of a morphisms. In particular I'm looking for a proof wich make uses of the internal logic as here:
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+on+ETCS+III

Comment: Please _state_ the definition of topos you are using, if you are not assuming that pullbacks have right adjoints.

Comment: I use the elementary definition of topos, namely a cartesian closed category with power objects.

Comment: You can find an "internal logic" proof in [_Introduction to higher order categorical logic_], Lemma 6.5.