# topos have colimits

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, limits-colimits

Define an (elementary) topos to be a cartesian closed category with all finite limits and subobject classifiers. I'm looking for a proof of the fact that a topos also has all finite colimits.

I know that there is a proof by Paré using monad theory; but I do not know yet how a monad works, and I would like to see an explicit construction. For example, how can one construct an initial object from the axioms of a topos ? Or a coproduct ?

I have some vague ideas coming from the example where the topos is $\mathbf{Set}$, for example trying to construct $A\coprod B$ as a subset of $\Omega^{A\prod B}$, but I haven't managed to make any of them work.

Comment: You should learn about monads. The concrete details are painful even in the case of the initial object: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493475).

Comment: Okay, I found indeed some ideas in here:http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+on+ETCS+III (I don't know how to do a link in comments), though not a complete formal proof. Indeed it seems painful. I'll wait to get to monads to come back to the problem; though I find it strange that the monad theory proof can not be translated into more elementary reasonable solution...

Comment: There is no reason to expect an elementary proof. Category theory may be abstract nonsense but it does simplify things sometimes.

Comment: There is no reason not to expect an elementary proof. And I don't understand what your statement about category theory has to do with anything: the question is formulated in category theory language, so I certainly wouldn't expect a proof outside category theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each object $X$ the singleton subobjects $\{x\}:\Omega^X$ are *minimal inhabited subobjects*. Call the elements of the limit $\lim_X\Omega^{DX}$ *inhabited* if the disjunction $\bigvee_{d\in D_0}(\exists y: Dd.x_d(y))$ is valid--here $D_0$ is the finite set of objects of the diagram $D$. Now the colimit $\mathrm{colim}_x Dx$ is isomorphic to the subobject of minimal inhabited elements of $\lim_x\Omega^{Dx}$.

Edit: I assume that if you want to learn topos theory and do difficult things like defining colimits, you will figure out the details of the construction yourself. I will add some *spoilers* below just in case.

Thanks to their internal languages toposes are like parallel universes of mathematics whose logic can be constructive and which can contains things of different types than sets. So instead of $x\in y$ ($x$ is in $y$), I write $x:y$ ($x$ is of type $y$), instead of 'non empty' I say 'inhabited' and instead of 'true' I say 'valid'. It is a more accurate wording that sets the internal language of the topos apart from the external language of set theory.

The precise meaning of inhabited in toposes is subtle. Each morphism in a topos factors as a monomorphism following an epimorphism. For each object $X$ the unique morphism $!:X\to 1$ factors as the mono $\mathrm{supp}(X)\to 1$ after the epi $X\to\mathrm{supp}(X)$. The object $\mathrm{supp}(X)$ is *the support of $X$*. When the mono $\mathrm{supp}(X)\to 1$ is an isomorphism, $X$ is *globally supported* or *inhabited*.

For each object $X$ a morphism $\chi: X\to \Omega$ characterizes some subobject of $X$ and this subobject can also be inhabited. Parallel to the support construction, there is a morphism $(\chi\mapsto\exists x: X.\chi(x)):\Omega^X\to \Omega$, and when the subobject that $\chi$ characterizes is inhabited, $\exists x: X.\chi(x)=\top$, the greatest element of $\Omega$. Other ways to say this are that the proposition $\exists x: X.\chi(x)$ is *valid* and that $\chi$ is an *inhabited subobject* of $X$.

*Minimal* means the same thing here as it does everywhere. If $x$ is a minimal inhabited subobject and $y$ is a smaller inhabited subobject, then $y=x$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. What does $d. x_{d}(y)$ mean, what is a valid disjunction, and how do you define a minimal inhabited subobject ?

Comment: If you don't know what a valid disjunction is, I suggest that you read an introduction to logic before trying to define colimits in toposes.

Comment: Thanks for completing your answer, though I still don't get everything. For example, what does $DX$ mean, is it the diagram with all arrow the identity of X ? If so, trivially $\mathbb{colim}_{X} DX \simeq X$. And why is there a subscript ?

Comment: I'll try to complete your proof on my own though. I guess it indeed constructs $A\coprod B$ as a subset of $\Omega^{A\prod B}$ as I suspected when I posted the answer.

Comment: A diagram $D$ is a morphism from either a graph or a category, depending on the textbook you use. For each object $X$ in the domain, $DX$ is its image in the codomain. $\mathrm{colim}_XDX$ is the colim of the diagram.

Comment: Actually, the coproduct $A+B$ is a subobject of $\Omega^A\times \Omega^B$ which consists of the pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy $(\exists a: A.x(a))\vee(\exists b: B.x(b))$ and that minimal for this property. In the category of sets, that comes down to pairs $(x,y)$ where one of $x$ and $y$ is a singleton and the other is the emptyset.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for taking the trouble to explain all that to me :)